# Merge information on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that looks like this:

> ```
>   Expression1    Expression2  CellType  Patient   
>      9.34          8.23         3.2      A
>      8.2           3.2         10.9      B      
>      2.12          5.3         12.9      B    
>      2.10          1.3          2.9      B    
>      2.12          1.5          2.9      A    
>      2.11          9.5          6.9      A
> ```
>
> ...        ....          ...          ...     ....

I would like to generate a plot (with ggplot) with Expression1 and Expression2 on the y and x axes respectively and dots coloured in a gradient of a single color according to the CellType column and at the same time distinguishing between Patient A and B on the same plot.

Can anyone help me please?

> ```
> ggplot(myDF, aes(Expression1, Expression2)) +  geom_point(aes(colour = CellType)) + scale_colour_gradient2(low="black",mid="white" , high="red", + ggtitle("First_attempt")
> ```

I don't know how to add a gradient for Patient

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like the type of thing covered in most ggplot2 tutorials? If you don't show an attempt, it is very difficult to know where you are stuck. Do you have ggplot installed? Can you create just the scatter plot? Have you tried using `color = CellType"` in the aesthetic? Are you getting errors, warnings, unexpected results?

Comment: Just edited what I tried

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work fine:

```
dt <- data.table::fread('Expression1    Expression2  CellType  Patient   
     9.34          8.23         3.2      A
           8.2           3.2         10.9      B      
           2.12          5.3         12.9      B    
           2.10          1.3          2.9      B    
           2.12          1.5          2.9      A    
           2.11          9.5          6.9      A ')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x = Expression2, y = Expression1, 
                            color = CellType, shape = Patient))
```

**output**

[image: plot]